# Remove items and indices from bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to remove those items of an array that also exists in another array. For example:

```
a=(a b c d)
b=(a d)

for ((i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i++)); do
    for j in "${b[@]}" ; do
        [[ $j == ${a[$i]} ]] && unset a[$i]
    done
done

for ((i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo "$i: ${a[$i]}"
done
```

The output is:

```
0: 
1: b
2: c
```

How to get rid of the dummy zero index? Expected output would be:

```
0: b
1: c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
a=(a b c d)
b=(a d)

for i in "${b[@]}"; do
    a=(${a[@]/$i})
done

for ((i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo "$i: ${a[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: This will recreate the array for each iteration of the loop.. is it necessary? I just want to remove an item.. I wonder if the arrays are large, it will be inefficient?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Yes, I'ts very unefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
 for i in "${b[@]}"; do ##for every entry in array b
     a=(${a[@]//$i})  ## remove the entry within a that matches exactly what b has
 done
```

Comment: Double slashes will remove all occurrences not only the first one?